# Check whether jQuery method exists

Tags: methods, jquery, hashchange

I'm trying to check whether the jQuery has a .hashchange method reference to the window object like

```
$(window).data('events').hasOwnProperty('hashchange') ?
    $(window).hashchange(hashChange) :
    window.onhashchange = hashChange;
```

but i keep getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined" in both browsers that support & don't support the function. any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

One way is to see if the property is simply undefined

```
if ($(window).hashchange === undefined) {
  // Not defined
}
```

Note: This actually checks whether or not the value is defined vs the name.  It is possible to define the value with an explicit `undefined` value but the two are probably equivalent for your scenario

```
var x = {}
x.test = undefined;
x.hasOwnProperty("test") // true
x.test === undefined // true
```

Comment: I am waaaaaaaaay to slow ^_^ `+1`

Comment: tried the top one it didn't work, here's my solution "typeof($(window).hashchange) === 'undefined' ?
  window.onhashchange = hashChange :
  $(window).hashchange(hashChange);"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).data('events') === undefined
```

Therefor it has **no** properties.

---

What you need to do is 1st make sure that the data contains an object:

```
var window_data = $(window).data('events');

if(window_data !== undefined){
   window_data.hasOwnProperty('hashchange') ?
    $(window).hashchange(hashChange) :
    window.onhashchange = hashChange;
}
else {
    window.onhashchange = hashChange;
}
```

---

Comment: but it does, it just doesn't load in time or something

Comment: @MariusMiliunas try in the console for this page.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but if methods are attached to the window property via plugin, than it has properties, for example, copy in the console - $(window).resize(function() { console.log('something') }) - then copy - $(window).data('events')

Comment: I don't know whether it's something with the order of jquery's initialization, but during compile time (after ready event) $(window).data('events') returns undefined in both browsers. like I posted in the previous post this was the only thing that worked for me there typeof($(window).hashchange) (either 'undefined' as a string or 'function' if exists)